# USB MIC w/ 3.5mm Headphones

Tags: ps4, voice-chat

I have some Razer Krakens (non-pro, no mic) that will plug into the 3.5mm jack on the controller.

Then use the PS4 camera for picking up my voice.

I don't own a PS4 camera yet. I did try this with my Snowball USB microphone and it works. All audio comes through my headphones but my voice is picked up via the Snowball.

I will be using my Snowball for my PC so I just want to know if this will work before I purchase the PS4 camera.

I presume it will work the same as the Snowball but I am just worried it will not due to it being a part of the PlayStation ecosystem and may act a little different. Otherwise I'll just buy another Snowball.

Can anybody confirm?

**Edit:** FYI this works, though now I get the sound from both headset and TV, I just mute the TV.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please post it as an actual answer (below) so that it's easier to find for future visitors. :)